# Powershell equivalent of "Open with Code" Windows shell extension?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, shell-extensions

When I choose the "Open with Code" shell extension in Windows Explorer, it opens the file in an existing VS Code window.  I'd like to do the same from a Powershell script in my build process to load some output logs into VS Code.

Just executing:

`& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .\install.log`

always opens a new instance

I have looked at the registry change [here](https://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/) but it does not behave the way the shell extension behaves - it always just opens a new Code instance.  Also, despite additional comments [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12147) about making new registry entries, that is not actually how the shell extension works.

Is this a case of finding the existing running Code process and sending it a message to open the file?

Unfortunately, using:

`Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq "Code" }`

with one Code window open, shows eight Code processes...

Or perhaps the existing shell extension code is already available somewhere so I can see what it does to get existing Code instance to open a file?

Issue is because VS Code has changed installation locations over time

[image: Issue is because VS Code has two installations]

Resolution: As long as you are actually calling the same binary as the existing vscode processes, it will open in an existing window (based on current operation).  So important to verify that you don't have multiple binaries due to installation path changes by vendor over time.  This also affects the registry fixes mentioned in the links above as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I run "...\code.exe" file.ext, it does reuse the same VS Code instance window. But I note that my VS Code is installed in %localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code while you use "Program Files". Program files is a restricted area, it may be possible that VS Code (using electron) cannot reuse an instance started in another security context for some reason. How single instance works is there *is* another process created, but it finds the first one by some way, hands off the work it (and terminates). Maybe it cannot do that in your context.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#apprequestsingleinstancelock

Comment: @SimonMourier In a fresh powershell, in a folder which also happens to be under the tree of the open VS Code, if I type code install.log, it opens it in a new instance.

Comment: I was not talking about the relative position of the file or folder you open vs VS code path, but simply the install path of VS Code, under %localappdata% vs Program Files.

Comment: I see, it looks like VSCode installation location has changed over time.  I just copied that path from the registry article and since it launched, I figured it was the one and only location I was always using.  But in fact, the one I use every day is in AppData.  Once I reference the same EXE it seems to use the existing instance (or the oldest of multiple instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this...

```
[Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq "Code" }]
```

...even to what looks like that you have one Code.exe window open actually it will always be 2 or more, depending on what and how you have VSCode configured. For example, doing this on my dev box brings back 9...

```
Get-Process | 
Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq "Code" } | 
Select-Object -Property ID, SessionId, Path, PriorityClass

<#
   Id SessionId Path                                                                 PriorityClass
   -- --------- ----                                                                 -------------
 1200         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
 2520         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
 5168         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
 6292         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe   AboveNormal
10856         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
13556         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
16920         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
19528         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
20424         2 C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe        Normal
#>
```

...and this is on launch.

Also, why are you calling VSCode this way?

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .\install.log
```

As on install, it gets added to your user path (unless you changed that on install)...

```
C:\Users\postanote\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```

... thus you only need to do this...

```
code D:\Temp\abc.txt
```

... when calling it from the PowerShell consolehost, ISE, VScode, et al, and it will load in the current instance you are working in.

I do this daily. Before the advent of VSCode, in the ISE, you call psEdit to do the same.

```
psEdit -filenames D:\Temp\abc.txt
```

If you are already in VScode, just hit F1, then backspace, then type in the full path to the file. No other code startup required.

Comment: In a fresh powershell, in a folder which also happens to be under the tree of the open VS Code, if I type code install.log, it opens it in a new instance.  It does not open in the existing instance.

Comment: I see, it looks like VSCode installation location has changed over time. I just copied that path from the registry article and since it launched, I figured it was the one and only location I was always using. But in fact, the one I use every day is in AppData. Once I reference the same EXE it seems to use the existing instance (or the oldest of multiple instances).

Comment: Yeppers, when I saw your path, I was a bit taken aback regarding why you were calling it from there. I have several systems in my lab that I use for different OS/PS/VSCode versions for validation, and as long as you keep the defaults, your use case would be met. SO, if this helps resolves your use case be sure to make it as you accepted answer for the benefit of other who may stumble into this. I saw this same use case come up today on another site, which I just pointed them to this exchange.